# multiprocessing Process vs single Pool.apply

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The code is running under Linux system with fork available.

Q1: It seems `mp.Process(f, args)` doesn't pickle the `f`, but `Pool.apply(f, args)` has to, why is that?
The consequence is that `pool` cannot work with nested function.

Q2: The time taken for `Process` is much smaller than `Pool`. Does `Process` pickle `args` like `Pool` does? How could it be so fast?

Q3: The answer to the above 2 questions might be becuase `Process` is utilizing copy on write at fork. If `Process` can benefit from it, why cannot `Pool` do the same?

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


N = 5000

def create_big_object(n):
    # Make sure memory is allocated.
    np.random.seed(1)
    return np.random.rand(n, n)

def f(a):
    pass

def main():
    time.sleep(1)
    my_array = create_big_object(N)

    def g(a):
        pass
    t = time.time()
    # No pickling?
    p = mp.Process(target=g, args=(my_array,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(f'Process took {time.time() - t} sec')

    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    t = time.time()
    # pool doesn't work with g because it cannot pickle nested function
    pool.apply(f, args=(my_array,))
    print(f'Pool took {time.time() - t} sec')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# Process took 0.0038743019104003906 sec
# Pool took 0.5500802993774414 sec
```

Comment: I would redo the test, but make f actually do some work. Right now, you're basically just measuring the overhead of the two methods. Pool might just have half a second more overhead, so on a real application where it takes an hour, it doesn't matter if pool takes 0.5 seconds longer. Also, there could be some kind of optimization happening with f being an empty function.

Comment: Actually I just noticed you are using g() for the Process test and f() for Pool. I wonder if it's because g() is in the local scope and f() is global.

Comment: This also depends on the OS, e.g. on linux, Process just forks the current process, so it doesn't have to pickle anything, as it has the same memory state as the parent. That would explain the faster time.